# Linux C/C++ allocate/deallocate memory in dynamic library

Tags: c++, c, linux, allocation, dynamic-library

I have to split my application into several logical modules.

`mainapp`:

- `module1.so`
- `module2.so`
- `module3.so`
- and so on

Where each module is an `*.so` library, which will be loaded during runtime.

Each module shares the same interface and will return some array of data. For example:

`int *ptr = module1->getIntData();`

Is it OK, to free/delete this memory on `mainapp` side?

```
int *ptr = module1->getIntData();
delete ptr; //(or free(ptr))
```

What about a malloc/free implementations. Is it possible, that library will use another one then mainapp?

Comment: You are probably OK, however it seems that if you provide a `createThing()` method you should also provide a `destroyThing()` method for consistency, if nothing else.

Comment: Are you following any synchronisation mechanism? e.g. `mutex` or something alse.

Comment: Actually it's more a matter of convention than a technical question. That is, technically it's ok, but it's important to explicitly agree which side owns data allocated by library methods.

Comment: Also I'd suggest to return something like [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), not raw pointers, because `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` allow to specify deleters upon object creation, thus simplifying memory management and making explicit remove functions excessive.

Comment: The choice between `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` depends on ownership policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that the module which does the allocation is also responsible for doing the de-allocation.  Thus:

```
int *ptr = module1->getIntData();
...
module1->freeIntData(ptr);
```

This allows different modules to use different allocators (malloc/free, new/delete, slab allocator, etc) without difficulty.

On Posix systems there can only be one implementation of `malloc` (and `free`) in a process, so if the definition of `getIntData` is "returns a pointer which must be free'd by `free`" then you would be alright.  On the other hand, I think it would be possible to write two C++ compilers which could be used to write module1 and module2, but which *couldn't* `delete` memory allocated by the other's `new`.  (Although I don't *think* such compilers currently exist).

If there is the remotest glimmer of a chance you might ever have to port this lot to Windows, then you *really* want the modules to deallocate the memory they allocated.  Different DLLs can have different heaps and all manner of fun problems can ensue.  (As @trojanfoe says in comments: Just the difference between debug and release builds can be enough to cause grief.)

I would only recommend using `std::unique_ptr` if you can guarantee that all the modules are always going to be built with the same version of the same compiler using identical compiler flags.  (I am a strong believer in keeping dynamic library interfaces as simple and C-like as possible.)

Comment: "ensure" should be "ensue".  Also, if my memory serves me, it only takes a Windows DLL to be built in debug mode and the executable to be built in release mode to demonstrate the issue you are solving with your answer.

Comment: std::unique_ptr could be nice, as I can pass custom (library) deallocator to it.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Ha!  Nice freudian slip :-)

Comment: @Dejwi:  I wouldn't trust compilers/libraries to make std::unique_ptr have the same ABI in debug and release builds.